# How to get the independent texts rects from the UIWebView selection

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using an UIWebView for displaying a small PDF. I need to get the independent texts rects from the UIWebView selection. I have done a lot of search and no luck. 
Does anyone knows how get this working, or at least a start?

Comment: Can you please make it more clear? Do you want to fetch text from a pdf? Can you post some codes which you were trying? That would be really helpful for us.

Comment: Hi. No, I don't want the text strings, I need the texts frames(rects) that I have inside of the selection view that the UIWebView generates. Thanks.